# SQL query to eliminate a duplicates in a field

Tags: sql

In DB we have a field named 'request'.
while updating the values we found that we are having a duplicate values in a single field.
Fo EX:

```
ID    request                                      cust

1   **25**;26;**25**;29;28;23;21;**25**;20         1
2   **24**;26;27;**24**;25;23;**24**;22;22         2
```

Now in the above table , the values in the field request there are same values in a single field.
now how can i eliminate a duplicate value in it?

Comment: first you ditch this table structure and normalize it properly. then you put a unique key on your new child table and the problem goes away entirely.

Comment: In terms of what the database sees, there aren't any "duplicates" in the column, it just looks like a VARCHAR column. The process that is inserting rows, or updating the value of the `request` column, controls what value is stored. To remove duplicates, the process that retrieves the value of the column can process it; it could also update the row with a modified value. If you need the database to enforce "uniqueness" of the values in the list, then store each value in a separate row.

Comment: It is possible to use SQL to extract individual values from the VARCHAR `request` column  into a set, and then return a VARCHAR with distinct values from the set. But the SQL to do that is obscene. The actual SQL constructs to accomplish that depend on which database you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, et al.)

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use a delimited list inside a field like this...

You can to:

1. split the field into into a temp table..
2. eliminate duplicates from the table
3. recreate the delimited field from the temp table.

Searching SO will provide method to each step.

You choice will be guided in part by your RDBMS.

Comment: I suppose I should add that if you make an attempt at this and get stuck the community here will be happy to help work through it.